# How to send a InputStream in play framework in an java only project without chunked responses?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

In a Java (only) Play 2.3 project we need to send a non-chunked response of an `InputStream` directly to the client. The `InputStream` comes from a remote service from which we want to stream directly to the client, without blocking or buffering to a local file. Since we know the size before reading the input stream, we do not want a chunked response.

What is the best way to return a result for an input stream with a known size? (preferable without using Scala).

When looking at the default `ok(file, ..)` method for returning File objects it goes deep into play internals which are only accessible from scala, and it uses the play-internal execution context which can't even be accessed from outside. Would be nice if it would work identical, just with an `InputStream`.

Comment: You cannot do it, without blocking, using Java. On the other hand you can do it without writing to a local file first.

Comment: Well, on a second thought, you could try [reactive-streams](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/) and see if you can fit that in your code. It's quite avantgarde so...

Comment: well, it's clear that reading from the InputStream would block, but i assume the client connection handled by netty should not block.. ie. if i'm using a 4k buffer, reading 4k buffer from that InputStream would block, but i would assume that after handing those 4k buffer over to play framework would free up the thread.. (until the next 4k buffer block needs to be read) - The assumption is, that this service from where we are reading the InputStream is still much faster than external clients (since it lives in the same infrastructure) so most time will be waiting for the client.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you need back-pressure... Long story short: you need to have a callback on the InputStream then you need concepts similar to Iteratee + Enumeratee to handle this reactively. Of course you could try to write all this in Java, it's possible, but it's quite a task mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I have now found a way to serve an InputStream, which basically duplicates the logic which the `Results.ok(File)` method to allow directly passing in an `InputStream`.

The key is to use the scala call to create an Enumerator from an InputStream: `play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$.MODULE$.fromStream`

```
private final MessageDispatcher fileServeContext = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("file-serve-context");

protected void serveInputStream(InputStream inputStream, String fileName, long contentLength) {
    response().setHeader(
            HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    // Set Content-Type header based on file extension.
    scala.Option<String> contentType = MimeTypes.forFileName(fileName);
    if (contentType.isDefined()) {
        response().setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, contentType.get());
    } else {
        response().setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY.getMimeType());
    }

    response().setHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(contentLength));

    return new WrappedScalaResult(new play.api.mvc.Result(

        new ResponseHeader(StatusCode.OK, toScalaMap(response().getHeaders())),

        // Enumerator.fromStream() will also close the input stream once it is done.
        play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$.MODULE$.fromStream(
            inputStream,
            FILE_SERVE_CHUNK_SIZE,
            fileServeContext),

        play.api.mvc.HttpConnection.KeepAlive()));
}

/**
 * A simple Result which wraps a scala result so we can call it from our java controllers.
 */
private static class WrappedScalaResult implements Result {

    private play.api.mvc.Result scalaResult;

    public WrappedScalaResult(play.api.mvc.Result scalaResult) {
        this.scalaResult = scalaResult;
    }

    @Override
    public play.api.mvc.Result toScala() {
        return scalaResult;
    }

}
```